# Network share not showing all files

Tags: windows-10

After recently upgrading my computer from 7 to 10 I am having issues with sharing files.  I have set up a network share directory on the computer however when anyone connects to it they only see a small subset of the files (ie seeing 10 files instead of 100's).
This can be either someone on another Windows 10 computer or Android.  I've even tried disabling the firewall with no success.
Any one with ideas on how to get something so simple to work?

Comment: So apparently this community has become filled with children instead of professionals that they downvote questions without leaving comments.  If you don't like a question or know the answer then just ignore it like everyone else and don't downvote, if you have an issue with the question then leave a comment explaining why.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue that's probably related or of the same origin.
Since I can't use my Windows 10 homegroup any longer (different issue), and I can't change/unset the homegroup, I set Advanced Sharing Settings -> All Networks -> Turn off password protected sharing. Now I can access most of my files, with the exception of some extentions, like .mkv
When viewing a folder those files simply don't show up.